# SplitFlap usage in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I came across SplitView for swift over on GitHub (https://github.com/yannickl/Splitflap) to animate text like those clipboards in airports, train stations etc. but I can't work out how (or if) it can be used in a SwiftUI view, the example code doesn't really give me any particular pointers unless I'm missing the obvious (which I probably am ... )

```
import Splitflap

let splitflapView        = Splitflap(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 370, height: 53))
splitflapView.datasource = self

// Set the text to display by animating the flaps
splitflapView.setText("Hello", animated: true)

// Defines the number of flaps that will be used to display the text
func numberOfFlapsInSplitflap(_ splitflap: Splitflap) -> Int {
  return 5
}
```

Any pointers on how to go about using this library with SwiftUI would be greatly appreciated or heads up on an approach to produce something similar

I have attempted using a UIRepresentable wrapper but having never used this before I can't seem to get any result from it.

```
struct titleView: UIViewRepresentable {
func updateUIView(_ uiView: Splitflap, context: Context) {
   // Splitflap.setText("Hello", animated: true)
}

// @Binding var titleText: String

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> Splitflap {
    let splitflapView = Splitflap(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 370, height: 53))

    splitflapView.datasource = splitflapView
    // Set the text to display by animating the flaps
    splitflapView.setText("Hello", animated: true)

    // MARK: - Splitflap DataSource Methods
    return splitflapView
}
}
```

Comment: The `Splitflap` is-a `UIView`, so just wrap it into `UIViewRepresentable`.

Comment: Apple has a tutorial on using UIKit in SwiftUI -- https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - I get the idea but haven't been able to implement ... (my first time trying to use UIRepresentable)